# how to get specific form FormData

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to use the html5 FormData api. Like so:

```
var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'))
```

but I have multiple forms. how do I select a specific form like for:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/timeline_events" class="timeline-event-form timeline_event_form">
```

?

Comment: You can you the name and id attributes or the submit button's onclick handler's this.form property to access form data in various ways...

Comment: You want to access by action or something contained in your question's final html line...  this.form.action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll('form')`. This will return you list of all the forms. Now you can get data of any form just using `index` on this node list like

```
var froms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
var f1Data = new FormData(forms[1]); //To get the data of first form
var f2Data = new FormData(forms[2]);
....
```

Or you can also add `data-attribute` to each form and select the required form with that

Something like

```
<form data-form="form-1">...</form>
<form data-form="form-2">...</form>
<form data-form="form-3">...</form>
```

Now you can use `document.querySelector('form[data-form="form-1"]');` to get the first form and so on

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a specific selector in your **[`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)**.

If you want to only target the form with the class of `timeline-event-form`, you can combine the `element` selector `form` with the `class` selector `.timeline-event-form` as:

```
var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('form.timeline-event-form'))
```

Comment: Could also access by onclick handler with this.form.action or .class